# Transposing Data in a Spreadsheet

Tags: linux, sed, libreoffice, awk

EDIT: To show data is not just numerical

I would really appreciate some help if possible please! I have some data in a LibreOffice spreadsheet that is structured like this:

```
+----+---------+-------+--+
| ID | Quality | Value |  |
+----+---------+-------+--+
|  1 | Height  |   123 |  |
|  1 | Weight  |   456 |  |
|  1 | Name    |   Jon |  |
+----+---------+-------+--+
```

But I need to transpose the data to show like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| ID | Height | Weight | Name  |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 |    123 |    456 |   Jon |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
```

It's a long file - 85,000 rows, otherwise I'd just do it manually! I have access to LibreOffice, awk, sed, and any other Linux tools. If it came to it I could find a way to use Excel.

Any ideas please? And is transpose the right word?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: "Transpose" is "mirror at the diagonal". So that's not excactly what you have to do. How look the other rows? Are there several ID's? Are there more different qualities?

Comment: Is the sequence of your rows always the same in quality column (Height, Weight, Depth, Height, Weight, Depth...)?

Comment: You can use `Index / Match` with Excel just a formula for each column and you can drag it

Comment: Thanks for the replies! There are many different Qualities and not every ID has the same Qualities listed. I'll look into Index / Match, thank you yass.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by using Pivot Tables.

Step 1: Select the data
Step 2: Go to Data > Pivot Table > Create
Step 3: When the Pivot Table is created, drag the ID to the "Row fields", Value to the "Data Fields" and Quality to the "Column Fields". Then click OK

Comment: Thank you Firee! I, however, made a mistake in not mentioning the Data Fields contain both text and numbers, so text cells don't seem to be working with a Pivot Table?

Answer (score 0):

I will write the Excel version of the formula, you have to try it and convert it when needed to LibreOffice:
`Formula 1`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Initial Tab]!$C$2:$C$85000,MATCH(A2&$B$1,[initial Tab]!$A$2:$A$85000&[Initial Tab]!$B$2:$B$85000,0),1),"")
```

Under Height column B Row 2
`[Initial Tab]!$C$2:$C$85000`  Value Column
`[initial Tab]!$A$2:$A$85000`  ID Column
`[Initial Tab]!$B$2:$B$85000`  Quality Column
A2 ID number in the New Tab
 B1 Height column Header in New Tab
`Formula 2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Initial Tab]!$C$2:$C$85000,MATCH(A2&$C$1,[initial Tab]!$A$2:$A$85000&[Initial Tab]!$B$2:$B$85000,0),1),"")
```

`Formula 3`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Initial Tab]!$C$2:$C$85000,MATCH(A2&$D$1,[initial Tab]!$A$2:$A$85000&[Initial Tab]!$B$2:$B$85000,0),1),"")
```

All Formulas are array formula press `Ctrl` + `Shift` +`Enter` at the same time instead of `Enter` for each formula and you can drag it down in the same column
For each `Quality` just replace $B$1 with the reference of the quality Header in New Tab
The formula will return "" empty if no quality for the corresponding ID
Just copy the column of ID to the New Tab and remove duplicates from it

**New Tab**

```
        Column A        Column B         Column C     Column D   
Row 1    ID              Height           Weight        Name  
Row 2    1               Formula 1        Formula 2     Formula 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to down load the spreadsheet to a comma separated file and use `awk` to transpose to another file and then upload it, this may work for you.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { s = "," } {
if ( NR == 1 || NR == 2 || NR == 3 || NR == 4 ) {
    if ( NR == 1 ) h[1] = $1
    if ( NR == 2 ) { id = $1; h[2] = s $2; v[1] = $3 }
    if ( NR == 3 ) { h[3] = s $2; v[2] = $3 }
    if ( NR == 4 ) { print h[1] h[2] h[3] s $2; v[3] = $3 }
    }
else {
    if ($1 != id ) {
        print id s v[1] s v[2] s v[3]
        id = $1; v[1] = $3; ix = 2
        }
    else v[ix++] = $3
    }
}
END { print id s v[1] s v[2] s v[3]
}' file1 > file2

   File1                  File2
ID,Quality,Value       ID,Height,Weight,Name
1,Height,123           1,123,456,Jon
1,Weight,456           2,114,115,Cat
1,Name,Jon             3,224,225,Dog
2,Height,114
2,Weight,115
2,Name,Cat
3,Height,224
3,Weight,225
3,Name,Dog
```